# How do I find out the license for each of my installed applications/packages?

Tags: ubuntu, licenses

I am using Ubuntu-15.10.
I have installed many applications apart from vanilla installations.

Now, I would like to find out how many installed packages are licensed under the GPL or third-party licenses (e.g. Fluendo).

Is there any way to find this out? Or do I need to check manually each and every license of each installed application?

**EDIT:**

Following snippet I used to list out the name of various installed License files.

```
find /usr/share/doc -type f -name copyright -exec grep "License\:" {} + | cut -f3 -d: | sort -u
```

Comment: Some packages have differently licensed parts, in particular the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is *mostly* GPLv3+ but contain *important* (but small) code under another license (read the [GCC runtime library exception](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception) license)

Comment: BTW, **why do you ask?** Motivating your question would help answering it. Perhaps it might go to [OpenSource](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question is perfectly answerable, and even scriptable — Ubuntu keeps licenses in a well-defined place.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27688390#27688390

Comment: I second @BasileStarynkevitch's request for the motivation for the question.

Comment: For people who've voted to close as too broad; too broad? Really?

Answer (score 6):

Packages' licenses are described in `/usr/share/doc/${package}/copyright`. This file is required to specify the main license of the package; many packages use a [machine-readable `copyright` file](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/) which lists the licenses of every single file in the source package.

For machine-readable files, you can use the `License:` line which introduces licenses:

```
awk '/^License:/ { print $2 }' /usr/share/doc/*/copyright | sort -u
```

If you're looking for a license documented in `/usr/share/common-licenses`, you can look for mentions of those in the `copyright` files; *e.g.* to count the number of packages licensed under the GPL or LGPL:

```
grep -l GPL /usr/share/doc/*/copyright | wc -l
```

To only count the number of source packages, count the number of unique files (binary packages shipped from a single source package have the exact same `copyright` file, or link to the same file):

```
md5sum $(grep -l GPL /usr/share/doc/*/copyright) | sort -k1,1 -u | wc -l
```

Debsources provides various ways of searching through [all of Debian's `copyright` files](https://sources.debian.net/copyright/); [here's a one-liner](http://oioannou.com/2016/blog/one-liner/) to retrieve the license of a single file (if its package uses a machine-readable format). (The license of that one-liner isn't documented, so I'm just linking to it, not copying it here.)

Note that since the `copyright` files document the licenses of the source packages, they may well document files which aren't shipped in binary packages and don't affect the license of the binary package; this can be the case for example with GPL-licensed files which are only used during the build for a non-GPL-licensed package.

Answer (score 3):

Most of software's licensing information is available at `/usr/share/doc/pkg-name/copyright`

Roughly you can estimate the number of program using `GPL` by means of:

- `grep -l GPL /usr/share/doc/*/copyright`

  But `grep` will also include files that are link instead of regular file. So, I recommend usinf `find` as follows:
- **`sudo find /usr/share/doc -name copyright -type f -exec grep -l "GPL" '{}' \; | wc -l`**

  It will also include file(s) like `/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/examples/ca-certificates-local/debian/copyright`, If you don't want them in counting, you can specify `maxdepth` with find.

Example (on my system):

```
$ grep -l GPL /usr/share/doc/*/copyright | wc -l
1949
```

```
$ sudo find /usr/share/doc -name copyright -type f -exec grep -l "GPL" '{}' \; | wc -l
1889
```

---

Note that a software may include more than one license per files in `copyright`.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help me list out the installed licenses from various application on Ubuntu 15.04.

```
find /usr/share/doc -type f -name copyright -exec grep "License\:" {} + | cut -f3 -d: | sort -u
```

Comment: This will only work for machine-readable `copyright` files; `copyright` files are still allowed to be free-form so there's no guarantee that they will have a "License:" line.

Answer (score -2):

I only have CentOS systems at hand, you can get to display the package name and license info with the following:

```
$ rpm -qa --qf "%{name}: %{license}\n"
...
ncurses: MIT
cairo: LGPLv2 or MPLv1.1
dbus-python: MIT
media-player-info: BSD
dbus-x11: GPLv2+ or AFL
NetworkManager: GPLv2+
...
```

<s>You should be able to do something similar with `dpkg-query --license` on Ubuntu systems.</s>

Like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/88412/41989), where he uses `$ dpkg-query -f='${PackageSpec;-30}\t${Homepage}\n' -W "*"` to show only a subset of information per package. Check the `dpkg-query` options to see if you can get the license form there.

Another [interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35052572/1052126) on this, talks exactly about this problematic and that:

> At the moment this is poorly supported, though there is an effort under way to provide machine-readable information in the `/usr/share/doc/*/copyright` files.

Comment: There's no such option as `dpkg-query --license`. Dpkg doesn't keep track of this information.